# invalid json response body at error while try to run npm install bootstrap --save

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json

i'm trying to learn React following udemy I'm trying to run `npm install bootstrap --save` on visual studio terminal (as he said) but I"m getting this error

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://selfcare.hutch.lk/selfcare/login.html reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 
0
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you add a link to that Udemy course?

Comment: @taylorswiftfan<https://www.udemy.com/course/react-tutorial-and-projects-course/>

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the incompatibility of the packages that the video tutorial uses with the packages that we use causes these problems.
The video may be too old and the installation instructions may have changed
Well, you can re-install

```
npm install
```

your node module and run this command again

```
npm i bootstrap
```

You can visit this site for more information

[www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap)